# uninitialized constant Mongoid::Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, paperclip

paperclip gem 
my gem file looks like

```
gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
```

and model

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Paperclip
    has_mongoid_attached_file :image
end
```

i am getting error like

```
 uninitialized constant Mongoid::Paperclip
```

i am using rails 3.2.11

Anybody knows what causing this problem

Comment: did you restart server?

Comment: and did you run bundle install?

Comment: yes i did both @SaidKaldybaev

Comment: After my machine restart its got working weird :(

Answer (score 1):

Putting this in the Gemfile solved it for me:

`gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"`

Answer (score 0):

I have added below line in my Gemfile and run `bundle install`

`gem "mongoid-paperclip", :require => "mongoid_paperclip"`

And add this in your model `has_mongoid_attached_file :image`

In addition to this, if you want to save different versions for the uploaded image then probably you will need to do the below steps

- Add rmagick to your Gemfile `gem 'rmagick'`
- In your model
  `has_mongoid_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => '100x100', :big_thumb => '120x120', :medium => '247x173'}`

This works for me.